# How to sync to codesandbox from github repo?

Tags: codesandbox

I created a `CodeSandbox` from github repo. How can I sync to `CodeSandbox` if there are some commits pushed to github repo? I see there is a github view on Codesandbox but it doesn't show any `pull` action.

Answer (score 6):

Visit https://codesandbox.io/s/github and import your GitHub repo there, you can push to your GitHub repo for your CodeSandbox editor using the GitHub button by the left-hand side of your screen, sign in then put in the commit message and create a pull request.

Answer (score 3):

### use [Githubbox.com](https://githubbox.com).

The simplest solution is to use GithubBox. From the [CodeSandbox docs](https://codesandbox.io/docs/importing#using-githubboxcom:%7E:text=Using%20GitHubBox.com):

> Append `"box"` to your github.com URL in between `"hub"` and `".com"` and it will redirect to CodeSandbox.

Example:
https://github.com/expressjs/express => https://githubbox.com/expressjs/express

Answer (score 2):

According to [codesandbox docs](https://codesandbox.io/docs/importing#import-from-github)

> The imported repository will always stay up to date with your latest commits. This means that any change to the GitHub repository will be reflected immediately to the sandbox.

Comment: kind of doesnt in my case. I have waited 1-2 hours now its still the same.

Comment: @TheFool The documentation is a little sparse & confusing. There are two ways to import a repo from GitHub, one of which is via the `Create Sandbox` button, then `Import Project`. This method forces you to create a _fork_ of the GitHub project, which apparently **won't** stay in sync. Second method is via the [GitHub Import Wizard](https://codesandbox.io/s/github) which [the docs link to](https://codesandbox.io/docs/importing#import-from-github). This method appears to create a template. I presume this version is what the docs claim will stay in sync.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/codesandbox/aandnjmckilnalnkmbmodifapcedaofn?hl=en) to run git application in one click.

Very easy to use.